# Custom Button to open Packaged Page with Parameters

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, formula

I have a managed/packaged visual force page `DetailPage` and I want a custom button on `MasterPage` to open it with parameters (the Id of the master record).

What *doesn't* work:

1. Creating a CustomButton to link to a VF Page (from the dropdown list): The list only offers pages which extend my `Master__c` object
2. Using a URL formula like `/apex/DetailPage?master={!mypack_Master__c.Id}`: the relative URL doesn't work once deployed because the packaged app runs on a different host!

I know I can make a VF page which redirects but this seems like overkill:

1. Is there no way to know the full URL of a packaged page?
2. Why is `{!URLFOR($Page.CommentAdd, null)}` not possible?

UPDATE:

1. `{!URLFOR($Page.mypack.DetailPage, null)}` doesn't work
2. `{!URLFOR($Page.mypack_DetailPage, null)}` doesn't work
3. `$Action` applies only to standard objects apparently!

Comment: Interesting! There's no support for `$Page` in formula fields :( one can fully qualify the namespace and pass in parameters: `{!URLFOR('/apex/ns__detailPage', null, ['foo'='bar','herp'='derp'])}` but you say the packaged app runs on a different host... even with `$Page` how would one do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though the managed VF page runs on a different domain, e.g. `namespace.na12.visual.force.com`, prepending `<namespace>__` to your page names will automatically send the user to this domain, no matter which domain the user started on. So, the correct way to do this:

```
/apex/namespace__DetailPage?master={!mypack_Master__c.Id}:
```

where `namespace` is the namespace that the `DetailPage` VF page is included in. Really, this will work, from any client org. Example flow:

1. CLient is on a record's detail page in subdomain/host `na12.salesforce.com`
2. Client clicks Custom Button on that detail page, whose URL is `/apex/namespace__DetailPage?master=<recordId>`
3. The client will be redirected to `https://namespace.na12.visual.force.com/apex/DetailPage?id=<recordId>`

Comment: Awesome thanks! How did you know that??

Comment: Experience :) Have to do it a lot.